# Jhipster with Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)

Tags: java, heroku, spring-boot, memory-management, jhipster

I have a jhipster monolith app, with a small domain model, I basically generated everything but did not code much. But in my heroku logs I get:

```
Process running mem=515M(100.7%)
```

right after calling the first urls.

These are my jvm metrics:

```
Total memory (290M / 307M)
94%

Heap memory (124M / 307M)
40%

Non-Heap memory (165M / 168M)
98%
```

And i does not got down even if no url calls are made. I am not very familiar with memory debugging in java, so any help is welcomed.
And I don't think increasing memory is a nice solution.

my yo-rc.json:

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
"promptValues": {
  "packageName": "de.tz.dudel",
  "nativeLanguage": "de"
},
"jhipsterVersion": "4.7.0",
"baseName": "dudel",
"packageName": "de.tz.dudel",
"packageFolder": "de/tz/dudel",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "jwt",
"hibernateCache": "ehcache",
"clusteredHttpSession": false,
"websocket": false,
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "mysql",
"prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
"serviceDiscoveryType": false,
"searchEngine": false,
"messageBroker": false,
"buildTool": "gradle",
"enableSocialSignIn": true,
"enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
"jwtSecretKey": "0d6598cbaf6cc68d9b96161707b17b7af086128d",
"clientFramework": "angularX",
"useSass": true,
"clientPackageManager": "yarn",
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
  "cucumber",
  "protractor"
],
"jhiPrefix": "jhi",
"otherModules": [
  {
    "name": "generator-jhipster-bootstrap-material-design",
    "version": "3.5.1"
  },
  {
    "name": "generator-jhipster-ci",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  }
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "de",
"languages": [
  "de"
],
"herokuAppName": "dudel"
 }
 }
```

Comment: Can you send add your .yo-rc.json file?  Depending on your choices (such as caching), the memory requirements can increase

Comment: I added it to my question

Comment: @GaëlMarziou ist about the same locally

Comment: So it'll be easier to investigate. Please try running a memory profiler to find which classes consume this memory and where objects are allocated.

Comment: It may be that your app is too big to fit on a Free/Hobby sized dyno. Try this guide, and maybe you have find some areas of memory that can be decreased https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-memory-issues